# Using images in React dynamically

Tags: html, reactjs, image, src

This is the situation. I have an object saved in local sorage that contains vehicle information like brand, model and so on. Based on the vehicle chosen by the user i want to load different images.
The images are in /imgs/mezzi and images names follow the patter "brandModel.jpg" so i tried to put in the src attribute of img tag the string "../img/mezzi/brandModel.jpg". Two dots because the img folder is on the same level of the components folder.
Anyone can help me?

```
import React from 'react';
import '../css/ListaMezzi.css';
import placeholder from "../imgs/placeholder.png";
import Axios from 'axios';

export default function ListaMezzi(){

  const ListaM = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listaMezzi')) || [];

  const handleSubmit=(mezzo)=>{
    if(mezzo.tipologia === "Automobile" || mezzo.tipologia === "Motocicletta"){
      let utente = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('log'));
      Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/verificaPatente", {utente, mezzo}).then((response)=>{
        if(response.data === "Ok"){
          alert("Puoi procedere al pagamento.");
          localStorage.setItem('mezzo',JSON.stringify(mezzo));
          localStorage.removeItem('listaMezzi');
          window.location.href="http://localhost:3000/RiepilogoNoleggio";
        }
        else{
          alert("Non possiedi la patente necessaria per noleggiare questo mezzo.");
          window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/AggiungiPatente";
        }
      })
    }
    else{
      alert("Puoi procedere al pagamento.");
      localStorage.setItem('mezzo',JSON.stringify(mezzo));
      localStorage.removeItem('listaMezzi');
      window.location.href="http://localhost:3000/RiepilogoNoleggio";
    }
  }

  return(
    <div class="container mt-5 pt-3" id="form-container-reg">
      {ListaM.map((val)=>{
        let srcImg = val.marca + val.modello;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(Fiatpanda))
        return (
          
          <div class="list-container">
            <button name="noleggia" id="registration-send" onClick={()=>{handleSubmit(val)}} type="submit" class="btn" >Noleggia</button>
            <div id="img-container"> 
                <img class="text-white" src={srcImg+".jpg"} alt="placeholder" width='100%' height='100%'/>
            </div>
            <h2 id="list-text" class="text-white" >{val.marca}  {val.modello}<br/>{val.prezzo}€/h</h2>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
    
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you include your complete React code in the question? Otherwise it's hard to guess what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Sure, code added.

Comment: Is the variable in  `<img src={srcImg+'jpg'} >` part of the component's `props` or `state`? Otherwise it won't re-render after the variable changes.

Comment: It's also a bit strange that you use `window.location=` because then your whole react app gets reloaded after someone presses submit.

Comment: no its not in `props` or `state` but it doesn't even render the first time.

Comment: what do you suggest instead of `window.location.href`? I need to redirect when someone press submit

Comment: And what if you console.log the values in the `ListaM.map` function? `console.log(val)`. If `ListaM` is an object from localstorage, you have to use `JSON.parse()` first before you can access `val.marca val.modello`

Comment: Why do you need to redirect? Mostly in React apps it's better to change the `state` instead of reloading the whole app.

Comment: Also, if the render happens before `localStorage` returns, then nothing is rendered because the vehicle is not part of the `state`

Comment: ```{
  "id_mezzo": "BO4682FC",
  "tipologia": "Motocicletta",
  "stato": "funzionante",
  "cilindrata": "500",
  "marca": "Benelli",
  "modello": "TRK 502",
  "posizione": "Via XX settembre",
  "prezzo": 60,
  "id_punto_sosta": 2,
  "addetto": 40
}```
This is the console.log of val. Its an object

Comment: So i should put the vehicle in ste `state`?

Comment: Yes, if that's the only reason you use redirect. If you change the state to another vehicle, the component will update the image automatically. Then you don't need localStorage either.

Comment: But.. This component i supposed to display a list with all vehivles returned by a query to my db. I need to display a different img for each vehicle. How can i use state for this?

Comment: That's a bit hard to answer in a single comment. But that is how you are supposed to work with React. You change variables using the `state`, and then React will update the screen. I suggest trying out working with state, and if you get stuck, post a new question.